# Why does "create table" yield an empty dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```scala
hc.sql("create table emp12(name String)");

res13: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []

scala> res13.printSchema
root
```

Why is the data frame empty but table is created in Hive when I am checking in Hive data warehouse?

```
hive> describe emp12;
OK
name                    string
```

Even when I load data from Spark, data is not going to Hive table.

Comment: You have not put anything inside table so it would be empty right ? 
What is your exact question . Please explain more clearly.

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava I believe user ask why `CREATE TABLE` doesn't return table itself. It wouldn't change if table wasn't empty (let's say with `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...`).

Answer (score 2):

`sql` method returns the result of the query as a `DataFrame` so it makes sense only for SQL statements, which actually return any data. `CREATE TABLE` is just not one of these - it is a SQL (logical) command that is executed only for its side effect, which is registering a table in the catalog.

If you want to get the table you have issue separate query:

```scala
hc.sql("SELECT * FROM  emp12")
```

or just

```scala
hc.table("emp12")
```

> Even when I load data from Spark, data is not going to Hive table.

That might be symptom of another problem, but it general you have to remember that Spark is no fully compatible with Hive, especially when using features like partitioning or bucketing.